# Entity extraction using POS and NER in spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, spacy

I need to extract entities from sentences using NER and POS tags. For example,

Given the sentence below:

```
docx = nlp("The two blue cars belong to the tall Lorry Jim.")
```

where the entities are (two blue cars, tall Lorry Jim). Running spacy NER on the sentence,

```
for ent in docx.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

It returns:

```
two 4 7 CARDINAL
Lorry Jim 37 46 PERSON
```

My goal is to append adjectives/number in front of the entities identified by NER together, in the case above, `tall` is ADJ and should be appended to the `Lorry Jim` entity. And `two blue cars` should be extracted using `NUM ADJ NOUN` from POS tagger.

Answer (score 1):

First, I have to say that the task you wanted and writing about is NOT what you said in the title. I think Entity has a standard definition, and for example, ADJ is not an Entity's part.

I think for solving your problem, you have to use dependency parsing and analyze the sentence's dependency tree. It could help you to find references for each word.

In another way, you can define a chunking task for your problem and build a dataset for what you meant and try to train a model for that type of chunking.

I think if you want to do this for functional usage, you need to make your problem very clear and also simple so that you can choose a practical method for solving the problem that you have. I think if you accept some error, you can define simple rules for any NOUN and ADJ parts so that if you have the POS and NER together, then you could solve it. It also depends on the language you want to work in. Like your example :

> blue car

In English, adjectives are commonly placed before nouns and this is known as the modifier or attributive position. but you have to care about sentences like this :

> All the cars he had were blue.

For feature works also you can look for coreference resolution like this :

> I saw the cars that he drives and it was all blue.